# Alternatives to taxonomy

Tags: biology, xenobiology, names

Are there alternarive methods to taxonomy for defining creatures and their relations with living and extinct relatives?

Comment: Eh, none, because taxonomy is — by definition — to define species and their relationship between each other. If you mean alternatives to *Linnean Taxonomy*, that is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: Taxonomy is a fancy word for what most people call classification. It has little to do with defining creatures; the only (weak) link is that when a creature is defined (in what is called a description), an acceptable scientific name must be assigned to it in order for the description to be valid; but the description remains valid even if later it is found that the name placed the creature incorrectly in the classification. If by "relations with relatives" you mean phylogeny, then the hard and unbending rule is that (modern) taxonomy **must** have a reasonable linkage to phylogeny.

Comment: ... Of course, what is a reasonable linkage to phylogeny depends on the point of view of the taxonomist. Some taxonomists have nothing against assigning names to useful paraphyletic groups; others view such practice with horror.

Comment: "then the hard and unbending rule is that (modern) taxonomy must have a reasonable linkage to phylogeny" - about just cladistics nonsense... as i suppose; They must have made up their own separate words for their own groups only ; but not to declare such nonsense as "birds are dinosaurs, and they are fish"; Nobody gave them the right (and won't give) change these terms of the dictionary and the human categorical thinking...

Answer (score 4):

"Taxonomy" isn't a method--it is the general name for the concept of classifying things.

Three different taxonomic methods have been common in human history. First, there is "folk taxonomy"; it's the implicit taxonomy encoded in the common names for things, which differs between languages. This usually involves grouping things by their cultural significance, which is how you end up with whales referred to by the same word as fish (and, well... "fish" aren't really a coherent biological group, either).

Second, there is Linnaean taxonomy. This involves grouping organisms by their observable morphological similarities, in a strict hierarchy with a fixed number of levels (or at least, a fixed set of standard levels across which it is assumed that you can meaningfully compare different groups).

Third, there is genetic or cladistic taxonomy, the practice of which has inherited the idea of binomial nomenclature from Linnaean taxonomy, but which dispenses with the fixed number of levels and classifies organisms based on their genetic descent and relatedness rather than morphology.

Comment: The idea of a fixed number of ranks in (non-cladistic) Linnean classfication is mildly exaggerated. I'm pretty certain that when I was avoiding doing any work to learn Zoology a Long Time Ago they had super-, sub- and infra- ranks to be used as needed. (And even entirely optional ranks such as "tribe".) (I seem to remember that Craniata = Vertebrata was a subphylum, and Pisces and Tetrapoda were superclasses, for example.)

Comment: P.S. Cladistics may use genetic (= molecular) data, but doesn't necessarily have to. Or else we'd never have a cladistic classification of non-avian dinosaurs.

Comment: AlexP, The cladists MUST have made up their own separate words (or smth like alphanumeric designations, f.e.) for their own groups only ; but not to declare such nonsense as "birds are dinosaurs, and they are fish"; Nobody gave them the right (and won't give) change these terms of the dictionary and the human categorical thinking.